# Getting ArrayOutOfBounds while creating ZipFile

Tags: android, unzip, indexoutofboundsexception, zip

I get the following stack while creating a ZipFile like:

```
final ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(mDownloadedFile);
```

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4096; regionStart=0; regionLength=-60060589
    at java.util.Arrays.checkOffsetAndCount(Arrays.java:1731)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:427)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.read(RandomAccessFile.java:290)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$RAFStream.read(ZipFile.java:407)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:142)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:309)
    at libcore.io.Streams.readFully(Streams.java:81)
    at java.util.zip.ZipEntry.<init>(ZipEntry.java:353)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.readCentralDir(ZipFile.java:365)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:132)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:103)
    at xxx.android.task.xxTask.unzipFile(xxTask.java:250)
    at xxx.android.task.xxTask.extract(xxTask.java:197)
    at xxx.android.task.xxTask.doInBackground(xxTask.java:157)
    at xxx.android.task.xxTask.doInBackground(xxTask.java:53)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    ... 4 more
```

I can not make it to reproduce the error. It is just somewhere happend in the world, in a live app, I got this error via our mail stack tracker.

There is a negative regionLength=-60060589? How can this be possible? Can this happened when I try to create a File of an already deleted file on the storage?
Like: Downloading - failed for some reason and delete the file - Downloading again - crash.

EDIT: The mDownloadedFile is a file that is created before the download starts. In a normal case it is created with new but in a retry case (when the download was failed for some reason) it starts the task again with the file. I removed this part now because it is not needed, if this could be the error i fixed it already but maybe someone know something different.

Some imaginations? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Some imaginations?

Here's my try:
If you store the length of the file in an `int`, then one potential cause could be that files with a greater size exceed the maximum allowed value an `int` can hold. With other words, the numeric value of the `regionLength` is too large to be represented by an `int`.
You can confirm this by trying to test with a big zip file, several GB in size for example. If this is so, then holding the length in an `long` could solve the problem.

Comment: nice imagination. but this is on the android part. ZipFile is an android class. As well my zip files are never big like this. They are arround 50mb to 200mb

Comment: but maybe it concatenates the files when it creates a new file from the given mDownloadedFile. And this will end up in a really big file..  does it concatenate files?

Comment: `all my zip files are never big like this. They are arround 50mb to 200mb` Well, this may not apply to the users who use your app. Having a tablet, or a S3 which allows you to have up to 64GB storage and hold larger files, changes the situation. Users can have large audio, video files, etc...

Comment: its not my fault ;) we changed it now to progressiv download but i just want to know why this could be happen. It is for a fix of the current version. until the new 2.0 is finished

Answer (score 0):

I found a line of code:

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mDownloadedFile, true);
```

The second parameter is append and means:

> If append is true and the file already exists, it will be appended to; otherwise it will be truncated.

In worst case this happend endless because of a retry feature. Normal case is 5 retries of downloading and unzipping. But in worst case this happened endless and the file will be big as hell.

Thanks to Andy Res and his imagination, this was the key to found this line :-)